# How to fix an always HIGH Input

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, esp32

I'm trying that my ESP-32 sends a high output to the Raspberry pi 3 B +. I already tried using different pins but the result is always the same. The Raspberry things he always gets a high input. The goal is, that the raspberry should take a photo when the esp 32 sends a high output. 
Before you ask how the ESP should know when he should send an output. Well, it is when he detects an object.

Here you can see my python code

```py
import time
import os                                                                                       # import the time
from picamera import PiCamera                                                                   # import image from the camera into the Raspberry
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                                                                          # define pins

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)                                                                         # setup pin 18 as input

if __name__=='__main__':
        #Variable
        cam = Picamera()                                                                                                                                        # makes the variable cam
    while True:

        if(GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.HIGH):



            #Define how newimagen is made of (Variable)                                         # make the variable fname which give us the date and Time 
            os.chdir('/home/pi/Desktop/image/')                                                 # Define where we are working now 
            images = [i for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if i.lower().startswith('image')]      # define what images is : 
                                                                                                # os.listdir returns a list containing of the entries in the directory os.getcwd...
                                                                                                # os.getcwd returns the current working directory of a process

            if images:
                newest = max(images, key=os.path.getmtime)                                      # max() is a method that returns the largest item of sth
                                                                                                # os.path.getmtime return the time of last modification
            else:
                newest = 'image0.jpg'


            number = int(''.join([i for i in newest if i.isdigit()]))                           #number is the number of the newest image : image1 --> number = 1. This method look up if there is an image and which number it has
            newimagen = 'image'+str(number+1)+'.jpg'                                            # newimagen is the variable that decide which image it will be(image1 or image2...)

            #Camera Code changing 
            cam.resolution = (2592,1944)                                                        # method to change the resoltuion

            #Main Code      
            cam.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image/'+newimagen)                                    # method that take a photo and then save it on the local desktop as the name of newimagen
```

Here my Arduino Code

```
// Define SensorS pins
#define trigPin 15
#define echoPin 2

//Define SensorXL pins
#define trigPinXL 14
#define echoPinXL 13

//Define Raspberry Pin
#define RaspiPin 26

//Define Motor pins
#define motorIn3 16 //Input 3
#define motorIn1 17 //Input 1
#define motorIn4 18 //Input 4
#define motorIn2 19 //Input 2

// Defines variables
long duration;
int distance;

// Define ActivateDistance
const int activateDistance = 40;
const int activateDistance2 =40;

void setup()
{
    // Sets the trigPin as an Output
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(trigPinXL, OUTPUT);
    // Sets the echoPin as an Input
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(echoPinXL, INPUT);
    // sets the Motorpins  as outputs:
    pinMode(motorIn1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorIn4, OUTPUT);
    //Sets Raspberry Pin as output
    pinMode(RaspiPin, OUTPUT);
    // Starts the serial communication
    Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void stop()
{
    // stop motor without duration
    Serial.println("STOP");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW);
}

void left(int duration)
{
    //Motor goes to left
    Serial.println("LEFT");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, LOW);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

void right(int duration)
{
    //Motor goes to left
    Serial.println("RIGHT");
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, HIGH);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

void forward(int duration)
{
    //Motor goes forward
    Serial.println("FORWARD");
    digitalWrite(motorIn2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn4, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorIn3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorIn1, LOW);
    delay(duration);
    stop();
}

long get_distance(void)
{
    //get distance from sensor
    // Clears the trigPin
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    // Calculating the distance
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
    return distance;
}

long get_distanceXL(void)
{
    //get distance from sensor
    // Clears the trigPin
    digitalWrite(trigPinXL, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPinXL, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPinXL, LOW);
    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPinXL, HIGH);
    // Calculating the distance
    distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
    return distance;
}
int turn = 0;
void loop()
{
    // check sensor
    if (get_distance() <= activateDistance)
    {
        Serial.println("Found an Obstacle!!!");
        // go right for 1 second
        right(1000);

        while(turn<4)
        {
          //turn on the Raspberry Pin
          digitalWrite(RaspiPin, HIGH);
          if(get_distanceXL()>activateDistance2)
          {
            //go left for 1 second
            left(1000);
            forward(1500);
            turn = turn + 1;
          }
          else
            //go forward for 1 second
            forward(1000);
        }
        //turn off the Raspberry Pin
        digitalWrite(RaspiPin, LOW);
    }

    else
        // go forward for 1 second
        forward(1000);
}
```

I've opened my Terminal and saw this issue. I am not sure if this will help with my problem :

```
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x1d13d20 (ENOSPC)
mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/camera.py", line 12, in <module>
    cam = PiCamera()                                                                        # makes the variable cam
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
```

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, but how about the connection, are you connecting both GNDs for Pi and ESP? Also, I suggest you measure `RaspiPin` with a voltmeter and see if it changes or not.

Comment: My Raspberry's GND  is connected from a Converter(which converts the volts of the battery to 5 V) and the ESP's GND too. They don't use the same cable but the same port.

Comment: When I oppen the Terminal I'll see this error message(I edit my post)

Comment: The error is your problem because your code never reaches throw line 12. It seems that your cam is busy, are you running your script twice? Or maybe another process is using cam. Try `fuser /dev/video0` and check results.

Comment: I do not think that I run the script twice. I only make using bash that he open automatically the script

Comment: If I enter fuser /dev/video0 in the Terminal he only says that the data name doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

There is a small error in your logic:

```
  if(GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.HIGH)
```

Instead, you should be checking if there is any input on your pin 11, like

```
if(GPIO.input(11)){
// the rest f you logic
}
```

Which will return `True` or `False`, based on if there is any input (current) going trough PIN 11.

`GPIO.HIGH` is supposed to to set a pin to HIGH, not to check if the pin is getting input or no.

Comment: `GPIO.HIGH`, `True`, `1` is equal.

Comment: The `if(GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.HIGH):` is a part of _python_ code but your suggestion seems to be written in another language…

Comment: It could be possible that I tried using my java language. But I edit my post because I saw a error message while opening the Terminal